# Merge facet_wrap() labels into one

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have this plot. I'd like to merge the top box of the facet wrap into one box, for those that have the same label. I.e. one box for hatch and chapel, rather than 3.

[image]

##### CODE

**note**: facet_wrap2() instead of normal facet_wrap()

```
library(ggh4x)
library(ggplot2

colours3 <- c(rep("#50808E", 3), rep("#B4EDD2",3), rep("#E86A92",3),rep("#F6AE2D", 3))
strip3 <- strip_themed(background_x=elem_list_rect(fill=colours3))
p3 <- ggplot(wtf, aes(x=year, y=mAODscale, color=cond, group= interaction(year, spigroup))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color='grey') +
  stat_summary(aes(group=fourLoc), fun=median, geom='line', size=1) +
  facet_wrap2(~fourLoc + cond, strip=strip3, ncol=3) +
  labs(title = "Interaction between Dam and Month on Water Table Data",
       x = "Year (Mar-Feb)",
       y = "Scaled Water Table (mAOD)") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

plot(p3)
```

Comment: It sounds like you want `facet_nested()` instead of `facet_wrap2()`: https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#nested_facets. If you make your example reproducible by providing a sample of data using `dput()`, you're more likely to get a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I used strip_nested within facet_wrap2(). See edited code below.

```
colours3 <- c("light blue","#B4EDD2","#E86A92","#F6AE2D", 
              rep("light blue", 3), rep("#B4EDD2",3), rep("#E86A92",3),rep("#F6AE2D", 3))

p3 <- ggplot(wtf, aes(x=year, y=mAODscale, color=cond, group= interaction(year, spigroup))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, color='grey') +
  stat_summary(aes(group=fourLoc), fun=median, geom='line', size=1) +
  facet_wrap2(~fourLoc + cond, ncol=3, 
              strip=strip_nested(bleed=FALSE, background_x=elem_list_rect(fill=colours3))) +
  labs(title = "Interaction between Dam, Year, and Location on Water Table Data",
       x = "Year (Mar-Feb)",
       y = "Scaled Water Table (mAOD)") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position='none')

plot(p3)
```